# How to best fill gap and sister ceiling joist unsupported

Tags: ceiling, load-bearing, joinery

I am trying to remove a door at a 45 degree angle and make it 90. After pulling back the insulation I see that they used the 45 degree wall to hold up a really bad sister joint for 8" joists.  With that removed there is nothing to support the hacked joist.

All I can come up with is filling the gap, then using another 2x8 on each side, bolting through in a w pattern and gluing.  The problem is whether or not this can adequately hold.  It seems like it just won't keep it from flexing when a human walks on it.

[image: Hack]

[image: Outside]

[image: Inside]

Comment: Wow, that's an ugly hallway.  Good idea to remodel.